# Rails: friendly_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I'm using [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem in my app. How can I get object's friendly id? When I write `@post.id` I get `1` but how can  I get `first_post` instead?

Comment: friendly_id used to change your app urls to 
http://example.com/states/washington
instead of:
http://example.com/states/4323454 ,what do you mean of first_post ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should a method called `friendly_id`

```
@post.id # => 1
@post.friendly_id # => first_post
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to @post.friendly_id:

```
@post.slug # => first_post
```